# How to set value to variable with quotes and symbols literally and reproduced exactly

Tags: bash

I have a value

> view/3dc84ea0-e9fc-11eb-841e-518effe6e821?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-15m,to:now))&_a=(description:'',filters:!(('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:

I want to set it to a variable. When I tried it I got errors or missed some symbols.
In powershell there is @''@ and the staff that inside is reproduced exactly like the value that I provided. Is there a way to do it with Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For textual data, I like to use a *here document* with a *quoted delimiter*, all inside *command substitution*.

```
var=$(cat <<'EOF'
view/3dc84ea0-e9fc-11eb-841e-518effe6e821?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!t,value:0),time:(from:now-15m,to:now))&_a=(description:'',filters:!(('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:
EOF
)
```

Comment: What if I want to provide there my value in some part of this text?

Comment: For example, I have
`Var=BlaBla`
And I need to get `"&_a=(description:'',filters:!(('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:$Var"`